# libgdx maven gwt: assets not found

Tags: maven, gwt, intellij-idea, libgdx

I created my project from the maven archetype of libgdx. Now I try to run the project as a GWT app but I don't get the assets to the right position. For some reason I have to set gdx.assetpath to an absolut path:

```
<set-configuration-property name="gdx.assetpath" value="C:\projects\<...>\assets" />
```

When I try to launch this from IntelliJ , I get:

```
error: assets.txt
```

and no further message. What do I have to do to get this working?

Update 1: 
For some reason, the assets get copied to war/assets instead of assets/ in the run/www directory which intellij creates for the launch.

Comment: I can't help I'm afraid, but I'd love to know if you ever got compilation working. The GWT plugin complains to me that it can't find classes from my 'core' submodule, and I've no idea how to tell it where to find my classes!